# file manager with role based permission

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I m a beginner to `PHP` and `MySQL`, I am having 3 user roles in my project:

- manager
- editor
- mtuser

Managers account can upload files to the system. 
Editors and mtusers are able to download file uploaded by a manager, they can modify those and reupload back to managers (feedback).

I am using a temp directory to store those files on the server.

I want to check with that file like suppose editor and mt user should not uploaded rather then downloaded files how I check that?

I also want to avoid collisions where several users try and write to the same file at once.

Comment: You've missed showing us the code you've tried out so far.

Comment: @RageZ: I tried my best to edit it, if someone understand what he meant on the two last sentence let me know ....

Comment: @RageZ: I think I cleared it up, he's worried about locking and races.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to make use of [WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV), which is [easy to do with PHP](http://php-webdav.pureftpd.org/project/php-webdav). This will allow other users to lock files for editing, so that you avoid collisions.

Regarding the rest, getting permissions is just a simple query away. I'm assuming that you have a table named 'permissions' or something that says what a user can and can not do. What I do recommend is not caching them (i.e. in a session), make sure they are easy to revoke.